# How to disable dragselection in Infragistics UltraGrid

Tags: c#, infragistics

I use Infragistics UltraGrid and I'm trying to disable drag selection. I have to limit selecting multiple rows only by holding down shift or control key.

In my `InitializeComponent()` function I'm setting ultragrid like this:

```
ultragrid.DisplayLayout.Override.SelectTypeCell = SelectType.ExtendedAutoDrag
ultragrid.DisplayLayout.Override.CellClickAction = CellClickAction.RowSelect
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable any selection in UltraGrid when shift or control keys are not pressed by canceling BeforeSelectChange event in this scenarios.

```
private void UltraGrid1_BeforeSelectChange(object sender, BeforeSelectChangeEventArgs e)
{           
    if (Control.ModifierKeys != Keys.Shift && Control.ModifierKeys != Keys.Control)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```